# Issues installing Drake on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drake

Followed through installation tips, but after typing
`$ python underactuated/src/double_pendulum/simulate.py`

I get

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_module_py).

If I run python3 I get

> ImportError: cannot import name 'FindResource'.

After typing `$ python3 -c 'import pydrake; print(pydrake.__file__)'` I get `/opt/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/__init__.py`

**Edit:** 
Full output of running python3

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "underactuated/src/double_pendulum/simulate.py", line 5, in <module>
    from underactuated import FindResource, PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer
ImportError: cannot import name 'FindResource'`

And full output of running python (without3):
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "underactuated/src/double_pendulum/simulate.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydrake.all import (AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph,
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import common
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/common/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._module_py import *
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_module_py)`

Version of python after typing python -V is `Python 2.7.15+`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the print test succeeds suggests that drake is installed correctly.

Please post the full output of running simulate.py with python3.